# Mutability of nodes in linked list

Tags: python, linked-list

I am just starting with Python and have been stuck for the past hour with this: When traversing a linked list, the usual way would be to do something like this:

```
def traverse(self):
    current = self.head
    while current != None:
        print current.getData()
        current = current.getNext()
```

I don't understand why `self.head` doesn't change here, since we do `current = self.head` and `current = current.getNext()` later. Is `self.head` immutable?

Comment: [Facts and myths about Python names and values](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are only ever assigning to a *local* name (variable); you are not assigning anything to the attributes of the objects involved.

In other words, only `current` is rebound to different objects, but `current` is a local name in the `traverse()` function. At no point do you assign to *attributes* on `current` or `self`.

This has otherwise nothing to do with mutability.

If you expected `self.head` to be affected by the line `current = current.getNext()` then you are perhaps misunderstanding what that line *does*. That line:

- looks up the `getNext` attribute on the object referenced by `current`
- calls the resulting object
- stores the result of the call in a name `current`, rebinding it if it was bound before.

Rebinding simply discards the previous reference, so now `current` is pointing to whatever `current.getNext()` returned. The previous object that `current` was bound to is otherwise not changed. If there were no other references to that previous object anywhere else in Python, then that object is cleared from memory (deleted). In a linked list, presumably there is still a reference to it from the previous object in the list though.

You could see objects as balloons, and names (variables) as labels; assignment attaches the name to the object by a string. You can attach multiple labels to any given balloon, but a given label can only ever be attached to one balloon. Rebinding, then, simply cuts the string tying the label to the balloon, and retying it to another balloon. Any balloon that has no more strings attached to it simply flies away never to be seen again.